D3 force simulation SVG is tiny and will not repulse nodes
I'm trying to get my graph visualization to spread out and not be as tiny.
You can see in this code I'm creating the simulation and then creating the svg. I tried using the .force() options for the simulation but there was no change in the svg.
Any advice would be helpful as I'm quite new to D3.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Service } from '../../services/service';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { Node } from 'src/app/shared/d3/node.model';
import { Link } from 'src/app/shared/d3/link.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph-visualization',
  templateUrl: './graph-visualization.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
})
export class GraphVisualizationComponent {

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  svg: any;
  public width = 650;
  public height = 1000;

  public nodes: Node[] = [];
  public links: Link[] = [];
  public simulation: any;

  constructor(
    public service: Service
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.service.getData()
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          if (response.data) {
            // receives array of nodes and sets to device connections
            const node_data = response.data.edges.map(d => d.node);

            this.formatData(node_data);
            this.generate();

            //this.generateSimulation();
          } else if (response.errors) {
            this.handleError(response.errors[0].message);
          }
        }
      });
  }

  handleError(errMessage: string) {
    this.error = errMessage.split(",")[0];
    this.color = 'error';
  }

  formatData(data: any) {
    this.generateNodes(data);
  }

  generateNodes(data: any) {
    for (let datum of data) {
      const sourceNode = new Node("uri", "name");
      this.nodes.push(sourceNode);
      for (let connection of datum.connectsToGraph) {
        const targetNode = new Node("uri", "name");
        this.generateLinks(sourceNode, targetNode,"1");
        this.nodes.push(targetNode);
      }
    }
  }

  generateLinks(source: Node, target: Node, conversationCount: string) {
    this.links.push(new Link(source, target, conversationCount));
  }

  private generate() {
    this.svg = d3.select("div#diagram")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.width)
      .attr("height", this.height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate("+this.width/2+","+this.height/2+")");

    this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation(this.nodes)
      // these aren't doing anything for some reason...
      // .force("link", d3.forceLink(this.links).distance(100))
      // .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5))
      // .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(100))
      .stop(); // not using tick because I don't need the animations

      this.createSvg();
  }


  private createSvg(): void {
    this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(this.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d: Link) { return d.conversationCount; })
      .attr("x1", function(d: Link) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d: Link) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d: Link) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d: Link) { return d.target.y; });

    this.svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(this.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d: Node) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d: Node) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", 30);
  }
}

Link and Node models respectively
import { Node } from './node.model';

export class Link implements d3.SimulationLinkDatum<Node> {
    // Optional - defining optional implementation properties - required for relevant typing assistance
    index?: number;

    source: Node;
    target: Node;
    conversationCount: string;

    constructor(source: Node, target: Node, conversationCount: string) {
        this.source = source;
        this.target = target;
        this.conversationCount = conversationCount;
    }
}

export class Node implements d3.SimulationNodeDatum {
    // Optional - defining optional implementation properties - required for relevant typing assistance
    index?: number;
    x?: number;
    y?: number;
    vx?: number;
    vy?: number;
    fx?: number | null;
    fy?: number | null;
    
    id: string;
    name: string;
    
    constructor(uri: string, name: string) {
        this.id = uri;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Data looks as such:

Current Graph Visualization at circle radius 25

Graph Visualization at circle radius 4
You'll notice that the lines pass through where the another unrelated node is - I do not want this to happen


For the last point: lines passing through other nodes, or otherwise minimizing intersections, is a difficult problem to solve regardless of library. More generally: D3 force layouts have no forces applied by default (nodes would sit in a phyllotaxis arrangement and not move). When you tried it, how did you set each force and apply it to the layout? (Ie, can you share that code?)

All code related to my D3 work is in this post. The forces are commented out underneath where the simulation is set.
I did see a few posts that ended up using a link arc that allowed the lines to curve which I will try using for one of my problems.

Your problem is the .stop().  Force layouts are simulations that need to run for a number of iterations so that the layout can be computed with regard to the forces.   See this answer here.  You don't need a tick handler but you still need it to tick.

@ChristinaLeuci, My bad, my mobile device didn't show a scroll bar in the first code block - in my haste I didn't look close enough.

@Mark absolutely brilliant - thank you. I ended up adding the following in-between where I call simulation.stop(); and where I call createSvg() --> for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(this.simulation.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 - this.simulation.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
this.simulation.tick();
}
